# Catching specific exception while inserting data in acces database

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0, ms-access-2003

I am inserting data into access databse and if the data is already present i.e. duplicate enty found then just need to update that enty.

```
 public bool InsertInToTooltip()
        {
            InitializeSettingsDatabase();
            OleDbCommand command;
            command = new OleDbCommand(//Query, settingsDbConn);
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                UpdateTable();
            }
            CloseDatabase();
            return true;
        }
```

Is there any specific exception thrown in case of inserting duplicate entries in acces database?

Comment: Why not write your query in such a way that you do not attempt to insert duplicate records?

Comment: Any example you would like to give

Comment: It is a little difficult without data, but roughly : `INSERT INTO Table1 ( ID, AText )
SELECT Distinct 98 AS ID, "AText" AS AText
FROM Table1
WHERE 98 Not In (SELECT ID FROM Table1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the record exists and the issue an insert or update rather than using an exception for this. You could wrap that logic in a stored procedure or do a select the an additional query.

All in one

```
IF EXIST (select true from table where id = @id)
    Update table set x = y
 Else
    Insert into table (x, y) values ('x', 'y')
```

Comment: This causes additional overheads in accessing database.

Comment: Executing that as a single statement will be much more efficient than executing 2 and even more so than your current method which has handle an exception too!

Comment: The question is for MS Access, that query is for TSQL, AFAICT.

Comment: With Access, you must execute more than one query for updates and inserts.

Comment: @Remou , Provide some example

Comment: Then do one query to check if the record exists, then based upon the result issue a second query which is either an insert or an update. The way you are doing it at the moment still uses 2 queries however you should not be using exceptions for program flow control in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DataAdapter if you are using controls such as DataGridViews, ComboBoxes etc... This will automatically do all the handling for you as long as you link it to a database source and control. Otherwise i would rather do an extra sql statement that will check if the data is available in the database e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = _VAR
```

Based on what it returns you can either INSERT or Update. I hope this helps.